# WAN bonding to a VPN server

Tags: networking, vpn, wide-area-network

We have some network issues with our ISP's and almost always have one WAN link down/repairing.

We currently use WAN Failover, however this cuts out our SIP calls midway.

I want to join three separate (different providers) WAN links together to improve reliability in during poor network conditions and throughput in good network conditions.

I have two linux servers, one inside the network with 3 NICs and one on the internet with 1 NIC.

I would like to be able to put together a solution where we present one IP to our SIP provider and the two Linux servers handle the routing of the packets over the WAN links.

We've been unable to use off the shelf providers of these services as inbound SIP calls are never routed to our location. We've been informed that this may be due to the providers performing NAT to route to the client.

Comment: You want to "bond" those 3 WAN NIC's. This can provide load balancing and failover across all 3 of them but will look like a single interface on the server. I can't provide an actual answer without knowing more about your network, however just searching for how to do linux network bonding should give you what you need.

Comment: @CR. So... you read my question and rephrased it as if it was an answer?

Comment: I did not post an answer... ?